# can a static class have multiple values in java (confusing example in android java)

Tags: java, android, static

How does it come to happen that every View has a unique `LayoutParams` attached to it but the class of `LayoutParams` is declared as static inner class of any layout (eg: GroupView ) in android java?

so **can inner static classes in java be instantiated?**  or there is a small structure that is set on the view when assigning that static Instance to them

I am Very confused

**If the class is really static how can we really do any parallel layoutparams assignment?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an inner static class can be instantiated. Moreover, because it is static, it can be instantiated without having an instance of the enclosing class. It works just like a regular class, except it has access to private variables of the enclosing class and its name is qualified by the enclosing class.

Comment: @kerolos - Correct. The fact that there is only one instance of a static field is an accident of the fact that there is only one instance of the class object (not to be confused with instances of the class).

Answer (score 1):

static inner classes behave like an ordinary java class so they can be instantiated as many time as you like

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question little bit. Can u be more specific about ur question

According to me ViewGroup is the Base Class for layouts and View containers.

This class also defines the ViewGroup.LayoutParams which serves as the base class for layout parameters.

ViewGroup  Class syntax :

public abstract class ViewGroup extends View

ViewGroup.LayoutParams is the static class

public static class ViewGroup.LayoutParams
                                              extends Object